# How common were ethnically mixed villages in pre-WWII Czechoslovakia?

Tags: social-history, demography, ethnicity, czechoslovakia

I was trying to find out whether the treaties that determined the post-war borders of Czechoslovakia were partly motivated as a punishment for the history of oppression by the German and Hungarian rulers OR whether the primary motivation was reducing future conflicts. I thought a good "litmus test" could be looking at the approach taken in areas with mixed populations. Not only both the [German](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Ce%C5%A1t%C3%AD_N%C4%9Bmci#/media/Soubor:Sudetendeutsche.png) and [Hungarian](https://www.hunsor.se/magyar1000ev/hungarians_incent_europe.jpg) population borders seem pretty sharp, I have found that villages in Slovakia used to be [categorized](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kom%C3%A1rno_(okres)#N%C3%A1rodnostn%C3%A9_zlo%C5%BEenie_v_minulosti) as "Hungarian", "Slovak" and rarely "mixed".

Am I correct to assume that at the level of villages, the populations were rarely in contact?

Comment: Czechoslovakia was carved entirely out of the Austro-Hungarian Empire at the end of WWI, and its border with Germany  was the same one that A-H had with Germany before the war.

Comment: After WWII, the borders were the same as before (except the Soviet Union took Red Ruthenia, and there was a small exchange with Poland).  It's not clear which war you're asking about, and the situation with Germans on the Czech side may be different from the situation with Hungarians on the Slovak side.

Comment: The post-WWII approach in areas with German-speaking populations was to expel them across the nearest border.

Comment: Germans were rarely villagers, they were mostly town dwellers in AH empire. Those villages that were German were almost 100% German and vice verse. Same goes for town districts.  Multiculturalism is fairly recent experiment.

Comment: Did you mean preWWI? And categorized by who? In the late XIXth century, there were many areas in Hungary where the population was bi- or trilingual. If you read the biographies of famous people of the era, you see that many were born in families with a mixed lingual background and fluent in both languages. Double, triple identities were (and still) very common: most Swabians in Hungary identify as Hungarian/Swabian at the same time.  Maybe readership (newspaper sales), the existence of active ethnic organizations at a given place are more indicative.

Comment: @rs.29 While it is true that settlers generally came in waves when occupied new areas, I don't think your statement is true. Populations were mixing between villages, especially during and after the Ottoman occupation. While many towns had a dominant German-speaking (Saxon, Swabian, etc) population, but other enthnicities (Serbian, Croat, Roumanian, Jewish..) were also common.  In the XIX century, industrialization and urbanization mixed the people especially in cities, again. Eg. I have Hungarian, Schwabian, Austrian, Slovak, Jasz roots at least 120 years back.

Comment: @Greg I mean pre-WWII which is also pre-WWI :) I chose WWII because of the [expulsion] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_and_expulsion_of_Germans_(1944%E2%80%931950)) that followed it. Categorized by whomever, I wasn't able to find any relevant data.

Comment: @Probably Pre-WWII is not the same as pre-WWI. There were a significant change, partly from migration out of the region at the end of WWI and after the new borders.

Comment: @Greg At least in the case of Czechoslovakia, it's really not "significant" compared to the post-WWII expulsion. In 1910, there were 3.2 million Germans in Czechia, in the 30's it was 3.1 million. After the war, about 2.2 million Germans were expelled https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Ce%C5%A1t%C3%AD_N%C4%9Bmci#Jednotliv%C3%A9_zem%C4%9B_a_po%C4%8Dty_obyvatel_v_roce_1910 https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudet%C5%A1t%C3%AD_N%C4%9Bmci#Situace_ve_30._letech

Comment: @Greg Well, you are wrong. As a rule of thumb, especially until 20th century, different ethnicity would live separately even in cities. You would have districts and neighborhoods which were Czech, German, Jewish etc ... Only in 20th century some mixing occurred in urban areas, but in the villages (which tended to be more conservative) this was practically unheard of.

Comment: @rs.29 If we could establish OP's intended timeline, that would be the beginning of an answer.

Comment: @Spencer I think he is interested in inter-war period. Then again, European villages are usually "old settlements", i.e. there were very few villages founded in 20th century. Population would move from villages to cities and towns, not other way around. Therefore, villages remained as they were considering ethnic composition.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, sorry, inter-war period would be the best, although I'd appreciate information on the earlier state (19th century) as well